# markov chain notation $X - Y - Z$

Tags: random-variables, markov-chains, information-theory

In a markov chain, there is a random variable $X_k$ indexed by time $k$, which takes values in a finite set denoted by $\mathcal{X}$.

In reading some research papers, I encountered the notation $X - Y - Z$ as representing a Markov chain. Does this notation mean there is a random vector $V_k = (X_k, Y_k, Z_k)$, which takes values in a set $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y} \times \mathcal{Z}$?

I don't really know what the notation means, I am just guessing.

Comment: Can you give a pointer to one or more such paper?

Comment: Often it is directional, $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$, which means $P[Z=z|Y=y, X=x] = P[Z=z|Y=y]$. Nevertheless this implies $P[X=x|Y=y,Z=z] = P[X=x|Y=y]$.

Comment: Markov chains can be read forwards and backwards. If $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ forms a Markov chain, so does $Z \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X$.

Answer (score 1):

$X - Y - Z$ means that $X$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent, given $Y$

$$p_{X,Z|Y}(x,z|y) = p_{X|Y}(x|y)\, p_{Z|Y}(z|y)$$

Also equivalent to $$p_{X|Y,Z}(x|y,z) = p_{X|Y}(x|y)$$

or

$$p_{Z|Y,X}(z|y,x) = p_{Z|Y}(z|y)$$