# Markov Chain Notation X-Y-(Z,W)

Tags: probability, notation, markov-chains

While reading some exercises for a course called "Information Theory and Coding" I've found the following notation to indicate a Markov Chain.

$$
X - Y - (Z,U)
$$

The actual image is a bit different and can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm67o.png).

I suppose that the basic notation is similar to the one explained in this question [Markov Chain Notation X-Y-Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422401/markov-chain-notation-x-y-z). What confuses me is the presence of the double variable in the last place of the chain. How can one split the conditional probability distribution all the variables appearing?

Comment: The double variable simply means you will consider the joint probability distribution between $Z$ and $U$. So basically this notation means that $P(U=u, Z=z|Y=y, X=x) = P(U=u, Z=z|Y=y)$